Nomenclature of [Purchasing] tag
What is a good tag for purchasing/acquiring/procuring pieces? I have thrown out procurement since it is not likely to be the most intuitive, but none of the other two above seem to be as accurate or intuitive.
What should we use, as least to begin with?

+1, this is a very important discussion we need to have.

My 2¢:
Take a step back and ask yourself, "What is this question actually about?"

If the question is about solely about buying, purchasing, acquiring, or procuring (or some other similar synonyms), then it's a shopping question and should probably be closed.
If the question is only tangentially about buying things, then purchasing is a meta tag—and those aren't useful.

Once you eliminate these, what kind of questions are left? That should help you figure out what tag (if any) would be useful.

Yeah, I had gotten distracted to work (since the Lego.se prop distracted me from working) and forgotten to ask that question. I think you're absolutely right. Basically, purchasing, in this framework anyway, is too general to be of any practicable use here.
